# Vue3 - reactive props & root component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am trying to show the zoom levels of a OpenLayers map via a Vue3 component. In Vue2 everything is working as expected and the vue component is updating while zooming in the map:

index.js

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import {
    Map,
    View
}
from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

const view = new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0
});

const map = new Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new TileLayer({
            title: 'OSM',
            source: new OSM()
        })
    ],
    view: view
});

new Vue({
    data: {
        mapX: map
    },
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(App, {
        props: {
            mapX: map
        }
    })
});
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>{{ zoomlevel }}</h3>         
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        mapX: {
            type: Object
        }
    },
    computed: {
        zoomlevel: function () {
            return this.mapX.getView().getZoom()
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

But I could not achieve the reactivity with Vue3.

Vue3 index.js

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import {
    Map,
    View
}
from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import {
    createApp,
    h
}
from 'vue';

const view = new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0
});

const map = new Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new TileLayer({
            title: 'OSM',
            source: new OSM()
        })
    ],
    view: view
});

const app = createApp({
    data() {
        return map
    },
    render: () => h(App, {
        mapX: map
    })
})

const vm = app.mount("#app");
```

App.vue 3

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3> ZooM: {{ zoomlevel }} </h3>    
  </div>
 </template>

 <script>
export default {

    props: {
        mapX: {
            type: Object
        }
    },
    computed: {
        zoomlevel: function () {
            return this.mapX.getView().getZoom()
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Using  `render: () => h(App, {props: {mapX: map}})` does not work properly. I would be very happy about any help.

Answer (score 0):

reactive data object is required to be plain js object, meaning its prototype has to be object. Your view is created as new View() so it wont work.

The same requirement is clearly stated for vue2 as well. But view 2 might not be enforcing it strictly

Comment: I  could not get this to work with a simple plain object either.  Maybe this is the reason: This is a general restriction with the new reactivity system: Any change to the raw source object is not observable.

Comment: how are you changing the data? within the vue component you will not get access to the raw object especially when you are using options api. But if your data is shared between vue and some other framework, you need to make sure everyone is using the reactive proxy.